# Foreign Key creation in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I tried to create Foreign key and PRIMARY KEY

My code is ok with `Table1`

```
CREATE TABLE Persons
(
P_Id int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
LastName varchar(255) NOT NULL,
FirstName varchar(255),
Address varchar(255),
City varchar(255)
);
```

`Table2`:

```
CREATE TABLE Orders
(
O_Id int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
OrderNo int(10),
P_Id int FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Persons(P_Id)
);
```

error :-ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis

Don't know what the error is.

Answer (score 2):

When you declare the FK "inline" you must not specify the `foreign key` keyword:

```
CREATE TABLE Orders
(
  O_Id int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  OrderNo int(10),
  P_Id int REFERENCES Persons(P_Id)
);
```

Btw: you don't even need to list the column name when using an inline definition, `P_Id int REFERENCES Persons` would be enough.

That will generate a system-named constraint (e.g. `SYS_C0066866`), so it's generally better to use a format where you can specify the name of the constraint:

```
CREATE TABLE Orders
(
  O_Id int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  OrderNo int(10),
  P_Id int,
  constraint fk_orders_person foreign key (p_id) REFERENCES Persons(P_Id)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're inlining your foreign key definition in the column's definition, you don't need the `foreign key` phrase:

```
CREATE TABLE Orders
(
O_Id int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
OrderNo int(10),
P_Id int REFERENCES Persons(P_Id)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

For MySql

```
CREATE TABLE Orders
(
O_Id int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
OrderNo int(10),
P_Id int,
FOREIGN KEY(P_Id) REFERENCES Persons(P_Id)
);
```

For SQL

```
 CREATE TABLE Orders
    (
    O_Id int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    OrderNo int(10),
    P_Id int FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Persons(P_Id)
    );
```

[Check Manual](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_foreignkey.asp)